# How to create shortcuts using the terminal

Tags: command-line, shortcuts

I know the easy way using the unity but is there a way to make a shortcut for chrome for example using the terminal.

Comment: short cut how ? Start typing a command and use tab completion, how to create an alias, or how to write a .desktop file ? custom key strokes ? what ?

Comment: i mean if i want to add shortcut to chrome on the desktop using the terminal how can you do that ?

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/106521/how-to-create-pin-unity-shortcut-to-a-specific-command-shellscript . You make a .desktop file, you can place it is various locations.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the easy way, but why not simply copy the existing desktop file from `/usr/share/applications` on to your desktop or wherever you want it to appear, and make it executable? You can do that via command line if you want to :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it is to use `xbindkeys`:

1. Install `xbindkeys`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbindkeys
   ```
2. Create the default settings file:

   ```
   xbindkeys --defaults > ~/.xbindkeysrc
   ```
3. Add the relevant lines to `~/.xbindkeysrc`:

   ```
   printf '"google-chrome"\nControl+Shift+Mod2 + c\n' >> .xbindkeysrc
   ```

   The keycodes above make Crtl Shift C launch `google-chrome`.

   You might need to get the right keycodes for your keys. Run `xbindkeys -k` and press your desired shortcut. That will print the relevant key sequence.
4. Run `xbindkeys`. To make this permanent, add a line containing `xbindkeys` to your `~/.Xsession`:

   ```
   echo xbindkeys >> ~/.Xsession
   ```

---

Now, once you have all that set up, and `xbindkeys` is running automatically every time you log in (because of step 4 above), you will be able to add new shortcut keys with this command:

```
printf '"ApplicationName"\n+Shortcut+Key\n' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc &&  
    killall xbindkeys ; xbindkyes
```

For example, this will make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> launch `xclock`:

```
printf '"xclock"\nControl+Shift+Mod2 + x\n' >> ~/.xbindkeysrc && 
    killall xbindkeys ; xbindkyes
```

You could then create a little script that does it for you. Save the following lines as `~/bin/keyb.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
printf '"$1"\n$2\n' >>  ~/.xbindkeysrc && 
killall xbindkeys ; xbindkyes
```

Make the script executable with `chmod a+x ~/bin/keyb.sh`. You can now add a new shortcut with

```
keyb.sh firefox 'Control+Shift+Mod2 + x'
```